How to forcibly run a skipped xUnit test locally?
I sometimes find xUnit convenient for developing quick test harnesses, these are only intended for me to run locally and should not be run in any formal testing.
From
How do I skip specific tests in xUnit based on current platform I learned that you can mark tests as skipped e.g.:
    [Fact (Skip = "local dev test")]
    public void LocalIntegrationTest()
    {

But now when I try to explicitly run the test, it gets skipped. How am I supposed to set up an Xunit test so it will be ignored by test runs, but I may still explicitly run it?
`

Could you use the Project Settings to set an arbitrary environment variable? Then use the SkippableFact method from what you linked to in order to make the test run only if that environment variable is set.
